# How does scala infers the type of a variable?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I am always fascinated to see how scala always infers the type correctly . How scala does it?

```
scala> val num = 5
num: Int = 5

scala> val num = "5"
num: String = 5
```

I know it might be a very stupid question to ask here but i don't know the answer. 
Please enlighten me.
Thanks!

Comment: How can the parser tell the difference between 5 and "5"? The same way you do. It "sees" the quote marks and attaches meaning to them.

Comment: It just a example. It could be any variable. I am talking about the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods for inferencing the type of a variable. Mainly using those called *inference rules* based in logic theory.

There are plenty of papers explaining the theory behind. Here I put a good example (with Scala ;) )

[www2.in.tum.de/hp/file?fid=879](http://www2.in.tum.de/hp/file?fid=879)

Answer (score 0):

While parsing the code compile can infer that `5` is of type `Int` and `"5"` is of `String` type.
In simple terms any value enclosed in double quotes `"` will be considered `String`, value enclosed in single quote `'` is considered `Char` and digits are considered Int (unless specified otherwise).
This is further used to used to infer types for expression results.

Consider this example

```
val a = 5     // translates to val a:Int = 5
val b = "5"   // translates to val b:String = "5"
val x = a+1   // expression 1
val y = b+1   // expression 2
```

In this example the code type of `a` is inferred as `Int` and type of `b` is inferred as `String`.
Based on this expression 1 calls function [Int.+(x: Int): Int](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#+(x$1:Any):String) which returns `Int`, hence type of `x` is *guessed* to be `Int`.
Similarly expression 2 calls function [StringOps.+(arg0: Any): String](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#+(x$1:Any):String) which returns `String`, hence type of `y` is *guessed* to be `String`.

Comment: Then How does it parse? I want to know how scala does it under the hood?

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal Sources of Scala compiler are here: https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.12.x/src/compiler
For example type checker (if you're interested in type inference): https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker

Comment: I notice mistake `x is guessed to be String` must be `x is guessed to be int`