# Are assignments implicitly covariant?

Tags: java, scala, types, type-inference, covariance

This must be a very basic misunderstanding on my part. It appears that assignments of parametric types are covariant without any indication on my part that that's what I'd want. I'm pasting Scala code for brevity, but it behaves identically in Java.

```scala
class Pet
class Fish extends Pet
class Guppy extends Fish
case class Box[T](value: T)
val guppyBox: Box[Fish] = Box(new Guppy()) // Mysteriously, this works.
```

An instance of type `X` can only be assigned to a val of type `Y` if `Y` is a supertype of `X`. In my case, this would require Box to be covariant, which I didn't say it is.

I wouldn't be too hung up on this, but it leads to the following odd, in my view, behavior:

```scala
  def unboxFish(fish: Box[Fish]) = ???

  unboxFish(Box(new Guppy()))       // Oddly, compiles ok
  val guppyBox2 = Box(new Guppy())
  unboxFish(guppyBox2)              // The compilation error I'd expect.
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: A `Guppy` is a `Fish` so you can create a `Box[Fish]` whose _value_ is a `Guppy` - This is why `Box` can effectively be _covartiant_.

Comment: That's not what covariant means. Covariant would be if `Box[Guppy]` extended `Box[Fish]`, which it does not. What's happening here is that you are passing a value to a function, when the type of the value extends the parameter type of the function. You can always do that, independent of variance.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, saying that's this is covariance (*effectively?*) is confusing. Covariance is different. `Box[Guppy]` is not a subtype of `Box[Fish]`, we can't assign a value of type `Box[Guppy]` to a variable of type `Box[Fish]`. We being able to use a `Guppy` where `Fish` is expected (`Box[Fish](..here..)`) is just [Liskov principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @DmytroMitin I didn't say `Box` was covariant, I said `Box` can be made covariant, because all a `Box` does is contain a value, as such it is just a simple wrapper over any value. Thus, it makes sense that such a wrapper can follow the subtyping relationships of what it wraps. - Again, I am not saying it does, nor I am saying that all generic types or wrappers can.

Comment: @EdwardPeters what you said is mostly correct. However, note you are using the word wording _"extends"_ is for classes, whereas both variance and Liskov are about types. - Also, _"can always do that"_ in a language with subtyping; not all languages have subtyping.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I see, you're saying not that `Box` is covariant, you're saying that `T` in `case class Box[T](value: T)` is in **covariant position** https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variance-annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala type inference goes not only from right to left

```
val guppyBox: Box[??] = Box[Something](...)
```

but also from left to right

```
val guppyBox: Box[Something] = Box[??](...)
```

(so it's bidirectional).

So in

```
val guppyBox: Box[Fish] = Box(new Guppy())
```

aka

```
val guppyBox: Box[Fish] = Box[??](new Guppy())
```

the type parameter `??` is inferred to be `Fish`.

[when does it need explicit type when declare variable in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756743/when-does-it-need-explicit-type-when-declare-variable-in-scala)

But `Box` is now not covariant. `Box[Guppy]` is not a subtype of `Box[Fish]`

```
implicitly[Box[Guppy] <:< Box[Fish]] // doesn't compile
```

You can't assign a value of type `Box[Guppy]` to a variable of type `Box[Fish]`

```
val guppyBox: Box[Fish] = Box[Guppy](new Guppy()) // doesn't compile
```

Comment: Thanks, @DmytroMitin. Perhaps I muddied the question by all those variance suppositions and the real issue, as you are pointing out, is how the compiler managed to implicitly cast `Box(new Guppy())` to `Box[Fish]` when `Box[Fish]` and `Box[Guppy]` are unrelated. Something about type inference of parametric types I need to think more about.

Answer (score 2):

`Box` isn't covariant. What's happening here is that `Box(new Guppy())` needs to infer the type parameter for `Box`, and the inference depends on context. When you do

```
val guppyBox2 = Box(new Guppy())
```

it infers the type parameter as `Guppy`, but when you do

```
val guppyBox: Box[Fish] = Box(new Guppy())
```

the compiler knows that the RHS should be a `Box[Fish]`, so it infers that the type parameter should be `Fish` instead of `Guppy`, as if you had written

```
val guppyBox: Box[Fish] = Box[Fish](new Guppy())
```